# Laravel Passport - How do you create a first-party client?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-8, laravel-passport

I'm currently reading the documentation on [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#approving-the-request) on skipping the authorization prompt for a first-party client. I have protected routes based on the scopes the clients request which a typical user would authenticate however, I am using Laravel passport as a Single-Sign-On server for my first party applications as well as third party and to this effect want to skip authorization only for first-party clients.

It is key to note that the scopes should still apply with or without an authorization prompt. My first-party client will still send scopes relative to the user, I just want to skip the authorization prompt and instantly redirect after login.

I created a model as the documentation suggests:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Passport\Client as BaseClient;

class Passport extends BaseClient
{
    public function skipsAuthorization()
    {
        return $this->firstParty();
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't not mention how to generate clients that are first-party, or how to upgrade a current client to a first-party client.

On inspection of the Database table `oauth_clients` there is no relative column or foreign table that would suggest a client is a first-party.

[image: oauth_clients database]

To this effect, I am under assumption that the `$this->firstParty()` needs to be implemented in the `Passport` class and a migration should be created to add a `is_first_party` column.

To this effect, the documentation further references [Overriding default models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#overriding-default-models) however, the documentation shows that the `Client` class is the default value for `Passport::useClientModel` but the created model suggests extending `BaseClient`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After some ideas, I decided to check the [Client class within Github](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/10.x/src/Client.php#L142) for Laravel passport.

```
/**
 * Determine if the client is a "first party" client.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function firstParty()
{
    return $this->personal_access_client || $this->password_client;
}
```

It appears that the client must be of a [Personal Access](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#creating-a-personal-access-client) type in order for it to skip the authorization.

```
php artisan passport:client --personal
```

Extending `Client` and then [Overriding the default model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#overriding-default-models) worked fine.

```
Passport::useClientModel(\App\Models\Passport::class);
```

My Passport Model now looks like this:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Passport\Client;

class Passport extends Client
{
    public function skipsAuthorization()
    {
        return $this->firstParty();
    }
}
```